# Convert LINQ to SQL when select new fire new query

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

Here my LINQ code in the pass name @ string and `CaseConfigType` is a enum value I want to convert this query in SQL. Please help me.

```
var selectedCase = (from caseList in ezrCaseConfig.ecc_cases
                    where
                    caseConfigType == CaseConfigType.CaseName ?
                    (name != string.Empty ? caseList.name == name : caseList.name != null) :

                    caseConfigType == CaseConfigType.ClientMatter ?
                    (name != string.Empty ? caseList.ClientMatter == name : caseList.name != null) :

                    (name != string.Empty ? caseList.ClientMatter == name | caseList.ClientMatter == null : caseList.name != null)

                    join dbServer in ezrCaseConfig.ecc_servers on caseList.server_id equals dbServer.server_id
                    join caseVersion in ezrCaseConfig.ecc_versions on caseList.version_id equals caseVersion.version_id
                    select new
                    {
                        caseList,
                        dbServer,
                        caseVersion,
                        baseDir = (from baseDirList in ezrCaseConfig.ecc_case_basedirectories
                                   where baseDirList.case_id == caseList.case_id && baseDirList.dir_type.Equals("R") &&
                                       (baseDirList.status.Equals('A') || baseDirList.status.Equals('C'))
                                   select baseDirList.physical_location).ToList(),
                        workFolderDir = (from baseDirList in ezrCaseConfig.ecc_case_basedirectories
                                         where baseDirList.case_id == caseList.case_id && baseDirList.dir_type.Equals("W") &&
                                             (baseDirList.status.Equals('A') || baseDirList.status.Equals('C'))
                                         select baseDirList.physical_location).ToList()
                    });
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882652(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Using joins in a LINQ query is a very strong smell. It means that you don't have the proper relations in your mappings. The same holds for the subqueries. Why do all this when `CaseVersion` could have a `DbServer` property? Or a many to many relation between `BaseDirectory` and `Case` ?

Comment: In other words, if you end up writing an entire SQL query with LINQ, you might as well go back to ADO.NET and execute the same query